# How can I sort some objects depending on one of their properties

Tags: vb.net

I want to sort a number of objects in certain order (ascending or descending) depending on one of their properties. I learned that interfaces can help doing this but can't figure out how to do this.
I am going to figure out what I want to do 
I'll try to shorten my code to only touch the problem

```
Public class Course 
     Public property priority as integer 
     Public property code as string 
     Public sub new (byval a as integer,
                              byval b as string)
     End sub 
End class 
Module module1
   Public sub main ()
       Dim a as new course(3,"ECE333")
       Dim b as new course (5,"ECE332")
       Dim c() = {a,b}
    End sub 
End module
```

So I want to sort the course objects at c descending order according to their priority

Comment: There are more than a few ways. You didn't post any code so it makes it a little impossible to help you. Also posting no code I would assume you didn't try anything...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can do for you until we have more information about the items in your question:

```
Dim sorted = items.OrderBy(Function(i) i.Property)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the List.sort method. You will have to provide a Comparator method to do the comparison.

Say, if your list is called myList and it has a property called height and you want to sort by height.

You can do the following:
myList.Sort(Function(a, b) a.height.CompareTo(b.height))

Comment: What if it's not a list? You don't know that as the OP hasn't mentioned what their using. Answering a question that clearly lacks details is just as bad as the question as you do not know what they need. Please do not condone this behaviour as some think it's ok just to post a question and have someone write it for them; that's not how SO works and we do not want that impression.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the feedback.